# Detecting mousewheel with onscroll

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousewheel

I tried by several ways to detect accurately `mousewheel` / `DOMMouseScroll` event, but it seems that the result will vary much from browser to another browser, and above all from hardware to another hardware.  (ex: MacBook Magic Trackpad fires many mousewheel events, etc.)

*There has been many attempts of JS library to "normalize" the `wheelDelta` of a `mousewheel` event. But many of them failed (I don't find the relevant SO question anymore but there are some that point this failure).*

That's why I try now a solution **without** the `mousewheel` event, but rather `onscroll` event. [Here is an example](http://gget.it/j0azjfa1/scrollDetect.html) of scrolling / mousewheel detection with a **hidden container** that scrolls (`#scroller`), and the normal container  (`#fixed_container`) with normal content.

As `#scroller` has a finite height (here 4000px), I cannot detect scrolling / mousewheel 
infinitely...

**How to allow endless scroll events (by setting an infinite height for `#scroller`? how?) ?**

---

Code /  [Live demo](http://gget.it/j0azjfa1/scrollDetect.html) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style>
body { overflow:hidden; }
#scroller { height: 4000px; } 
#fixed_container { position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; }
#text { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  console.log("scroll event detected! " + window.pageXOffset + " " + window.pageYOffset);
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="scroller"></div>
<div id="fixed_container">
<div id="text">
Bonjour
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal Of course, I already tried `DOMMouseScroll`, but as mentionned in my question, the result of `wheelDelta` varies **a lot** from browser to another browser, from hardware to another hardware... That's why I wanted to try something else

Answer (score 1):

*"How to allow endless scroll events"*

This should do it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var st= $(window).scrollTop();
  var wh= $(window).height();
  var sh= $('#scroller').height();

  if(sh < st+wh*2) {
    $('#scroller').css({
      height: st+wh*2
    });
  };
});
```

Tested in IE11, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

In the fiddle below, clicking adds text, so you can see it scroll:

### Fiddle

Comment: Great @RickHitchcock ! What would be great is that it's endless not only on bottom, but also on top (so that it's endless with PG UP or PG DOWN)... And second thing, that when we scroll up, the height is also reduced (i.e. won't have to keep a div of 1000000px height in memory if it's not needed anymore)... Any idea on that?

Comment: That's more difficult, because x/y coordinates for all children would need to be moved *down* in order to simulate scrolling *up*.  I'll give it some thought.

Comment: No need for that @RickHitchcock, because my `#scroller` is a *hidden* div that is only useful for tracking the scrolling events: there is no content in this div. It is easier then ?

Comment: If content appears anywhere within `#scroller`'s extent, it may need to be moved in order to simulate scrolling up.

Comment: I don't think so, have a look at this : http://gget.it/j0azjfa1/scrollDetect.html  : #scroller (empty and hidden) is being scrolled, but #fixed_container is not impacted, so that's ok.

Comment: Nothing appears in my console when I try to scroll that site(?)

Comment: Which browser ? By the way, be sure to give the focus to the HTML page by clicking near the text Bonjour before scrolling (by default when opening the JS Console Tab, focus was on the Console Tab for me)

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  Based on the source code, I wouldn't expect it to scroll, since you've got overflow:hidden on the body.  Do you get an alert when scrolling in this fiddle?: http://jsfiddle.net/dhne0dbj/

Comment: Yes I get an alert : Firefox triggers a `onscroll` even if `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Ahh, very interesting.  Firefox triggers it when pressing Page Up and Page Down, but Chrome, IE, and Opera do not.  Firefox's behavior is surprising in this context.